# a little bit of python help

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i need a little help here, since i am new to python, i am trying to do a nice app that can tell me if my website is down or not, then send it to twitter.

```
class Tweet(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    import oauth
    client = oauth.TwitterClient(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
                                 TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                                 None
                                 )

    webstatus = {"status": "this is where the site status need's to be",
                 "lat": 44.42765100, 
                 "long":26.103172
                 }

    client.make_request('http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json',
                        token=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                        secret=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
                        additional_params=webstatus,
                        protected=True,
                        method='POST'
                        )
    self.response.out.write(webstatus)


def main():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', Tweet)])
  util.run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

now the check website part is missing, so i am extremely new to python and i need a little bit of help

any idea of a function/class that can check a specific url and the answer/error code can be send to twitter using the upper script

and i need a little bit of help at implementing url check in the script above, this is my first time interacting with python.

if you are wondering, upper class uses https://github.com/mikeknapp/AppEngine-OAuth-Library lib

cheers

PS: the url check functionality need's to be based on `urlfetch` class, more safe for google appengine

Comment: Are you trying to tell if your website is down or if twitter down?

Comment: -1: you accepted the answer without testing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Google App Engine [URL Fetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) API.
The [fetch()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction.html) function returns a [Response object](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/responseobjects.html) containing the HTTP status_code.

Just fetch the url and check the status with something like this:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
def is_down(url):
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url, method = urlfetch.HEAD)
    return result.status_code != 200
```

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use `fetch(url, method=urlfetch.HEAD)` so that only HTTP headers are returned instead of a whole web page's content.

Comment: @Giulio Just make sure your app supports HEAD requests; some frameworks don't by default.

Comment: +1, your answer is the right one. Pity necenzurat accepted the other so fast.

Answer (score 1):

Checking if a website exists:

```
import httplib
from httplib import HTTP
from urlparse import urlparse

def checkUrl(url):
    p = urlparse(url)
    h = HTTP(p[1])
    h.putrequest('HEAD', p[2])
    h.endheaders()
    return h.getreply()[0] == httplib.OK
```

We only get the header of a given URL and check the response code of the web server.

**Update:** The last line is modified according to the remark of Daenyth.

Comment: The last two lines should really be `return h.getreply()[0] == httplib.OK`

Comment: Recommendation: Have a special status request to your website to get better diagnostics than requesting a webpage.  This would then be easier to parse since you could have it be JSON or a native data type. With python I generally have a /status url on my sites.  With simpler PHP sites I check for a $_REQUEST['status'] variable.

Comment: i did the php script in like 10 minutes and used the curl error report as the message

Comment: I think httplib is not available inside GAE sandbox.